# Функция filter_var php

Tags: php

В php есть функция под названием `filter_var`. Так вот, там есть очищающие фильтры.

Вопрос следующий:

Фильтр `FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES`, судя по его  [описанию](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.sanitize.php) просто применяет функцию `addslashes()` к переменной. И все... Так вот, что лучше использовать? `addslashes()` или `filter_var` с фильтром `FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES`. И что бы вы использовали?

Answer (score 1):

**Разумеется**, ни в коем случае не применять ни то ни другое.

Ни малейшего смысла применять данный фильтр нет. При этом вред от него огромный.

Поэтому просто забываем про волшебные кавычки и addslashes() как про страшный сон, как это уже много лет как сделала цивилизованная часть РНР сообщества

Comment: Вообще, применимость addslashes не заканчивается на экранировании magic quotes

Answer (score 0):

В filter_var можно можно передавать фильтры вычисляемые в рантайме, по необходимости. Тогда как addslashes делает ровно то, что делает и ничего более.

Например такой вариант (с потолка):

```
class PrepareData {
    function filter($data, array $filters){
        foreach($filters as $filter){
            $data = filter_var($data, $filter);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

В целом, filter_var стоит использовать там, где хочется получить единообразия в обработке схожих ситуаций. Допустим у вас switch на десяток case'ов на все случаи жизни и во всех  filter_var, а в одном addslashes - не аккуратьненько. Если же вам на весь проект нужен только один этот фильтр, то родная функция addslashes будет более уместна и чуть-чуть более быстра.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, как передать несколько фильтров сразу? Через || ?

Comment: Упс, это я вас обманул, извините. Там флаги к фильтрам передаются, а не дополнительные фильтры. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: А есть возможность использовать сразу несколько фильтров?

Comment: Сразу - нет, только через обертки. Один из примеров я в ответ добавил.